# Implementing a filter with Predicate<T> in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

To get the grips on to Java8, I am trying to implement a simple Repo for storing Lists of different Objects.

My startingpoint is this:

```
public class MyRepo {

    Map<Class, List<?>> repo =new HashMap<>();

    public List<?> get(Class c){
        List<?> result= repo.get(c);
        return (result==null)?new ArrayList<>():(List<?>) result;
    }

    public void put(Class c,List<?> l){
        repo.put(c, l);
    }
}
```

So I am able to insert Lists and retrieve lists.

My next step would be to implement a generic filter-method:

```
public List<?> find(Class c, Predicate<?> predicate){
    List<?> result= repo.get(c);
    return (result==null)?new ArrayList<>():(List<?>)result.stream().filter(predicate);
}
```

which results in

```
java: incompatible types: java.util.function.Predicate<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super capture#2 of ?>
```

How to implement a generic find-method?

I have to admit, that I am not sure, that the design with

```
Map<Class, List<?>> repo =new HashMap<>();
```

is a good choice. Maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you should make your methods generic, that will let compiler decide which `Predicate` you are passing, and infer a particular type accordingly. Also, `result.stream().filter(predicate)` will give you a `Stream` and not a `List`. You need to collect the stream in a `List`.

Moreover, since you already have the `get(Class<T>)` method, you can use that instead of doing `repo.get(c)` method in `find()` method. And you can also use [`java.util.Optional`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class here:

```
Map<Class, List<?>> repo =new HashMap<>();

public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> c){
    return Optional.ofNullable((List<T>)repo.get(c)).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
}

public <T> void put(Class<T> c,List<T> l){
    repo.put(c, l);
}

public <T> List<T> find(Class<T> c, Predicate<T> predicate){
    return get(c).stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes - Generics were the better solution. +1 for `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix up your method signatures.  Generic wildcard types are inherently independent - the Java compiler has no reason to believe one `?` type is in any way related to another `?` type.

Try:

```
public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> c)

public <T> void put(Class<T> c, List<T> list)

public <T> List<T> find(Class<T> c, Predicate<T> predicate)
```

This configurable `<T>` parameter lets the caller specify any type they wish, but also lets the compiler know that "Hey, this `List<T>` and `Predicate<T>`?  That's the same `T`, so you can totally do filtering"